# How to get a program to continue reading input after if statements are fulfilled (Morse Translator)

Tags: java, if-statement, morse-code

Before I begin, I am a novice programmer having only been doing this for about a day.

How do I get my program to continue reading my input after an input has been fulfilled? for the below code, which is for a morse code to english translator I am trying to make, when I input morse, for example .-, it gives me the correct output, A. But when I combine morse letters, example .--..., which should be AB, the else statement activates. What should I do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MorseTranslator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Please enter morse code you wish to translate.");
     Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
     String morse = sc.next();



     if (morse.equals(" ")) {
         System.out.print(" ");
        }
     if (morse.equals(".-")){
         System.out.print("A");
        }
     if (morse.equals("-...")){
         System.out.print("B");
        }
     if (morse.equals("-.-.")){
         System.out.print("C");
        }
     if (morse.equals("-..")){
         System.out.print("D");
        }
     if (morse.equals(".")){
         System.out.print("E");
        }
     if (morse.equals("..-.")){
         System.out.print("F");
        }


     else System.out.println("Please input morse code.");

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.equals()  compares complete strings, so .--... will never be equals to .- , so what you need is to 'look for' inside the morse String, using String.indexOf()

```
 if(morse.indexOf(".-")!=-1){
    System.out.print("A");
    //need more magic here
 }
```

now you need to 'substract' or takeout those two characters from the morse string, and repeat the searching with a loop.

```
 if(morse.indexOf(".-")!=-1){
    System.out.print("A");
    morse=morse.substring(morse.indexOf(".-")+2); // where 2 morse characters
    continue; //your hypothetical loop
 }
 if(morse.indexOf("-...")!=-1){
    System.out.print("B");
    morse=morse.substring(morse.indexOf("-...")+4); // where 4 morse characters
    continue; //your hypothetical loop
 }
 ...
```

don't forget to loop until there's no more data to process

Comment: this seems to be what I am looking for, but I want to be able to understand what I am writing. What does the 

    !=-1

do?

Comment: `indexOf()` is a little different from `equals()` , `equals()` returns a boolean value, `true` if both string are equal and `false` if the aren't... `indexOf()` returns the actual position inside the morse string, that position goes from 0 to the size of morse (minus 1) say in your case .--... and if you look for .- indexOf will give you the value 0 which says that that string is at the beginning of the morse string... if indexOf can't find the string, it will return the value -1... so if the return value from indexOf is different from -1 it found it (even at pos 0) hence (!= means different).

Comment: Looks good, but i get an error saying continue cannot be used outside of a loop

Comment: oh yeah, the `continue` is for when you put everything inside a loop, so at first please take them out... then read about loops like `for, do , while`

Comment: Turns out this works just fine for .--..., giving me AB, but -....- only gives me A instead of BA. What gives?

Comment: mmm, you are right, it will depend on how you will implement the loop, ,but it seems it'll be better to look the string exactly at the beginning of the morse string, so please change the conditional to: `if(morse.indexOf("-...")==0)` (instead of !=-1 change it to ==0), that way it'll catch both .--... as AB and -....- as B only, just because you need to loop it to catch the A again...

Answer (score 1):

You could add a loop before your `if`(s). And since you're using [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) I'd suggest using [`Scanner.hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--) as the loop condition. Something like,

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String morse = sc.next();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Eclipse then sends me the message that morse is a duplicate local variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Define (and initialize) `morse` once. Inside the loop. Also, you probably meant to use `else if`(s). Otherwise your last `if` is the only the one tested with the final `else`.

Comment: Doesn't String morse = sc.next(); define and initialize morse?